# Host can't talk to the guest VM when the IP is changed from DHCP assigned dynamic to static

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, nat

**TL;DR:** Host can ping NAT connected Guest VM when DHCP IP is used on guest, can't when static ip used. Help.

---

So I've been trying to setup a NAT based LAN that the host can communicate with where each VM has a static IP. According to VMware docs, the vmnet virtual switch has a host adapter connected to it, which shows up as 'vmnet#' (where # is the adapter number) in the host's `ifconfig` output. Using this virtual interface, the host can ping and communicate with the guest VMs connected to the same vmnet# virtual switch.

Now, at first I created a new virtual switch called vmnet10. I configured it to have a subnet IP of `10.0.99.0/24` (NetMask: `255.255.255.0`), a NAT device with the IP of `10.0.99.2` and a DHCP server (which according to VMware docs, resides on 10.0.99.254). I didn't change the automated DHCP settings, and thus the range `10.0.99.128 - 10.0.99.253` are dynamic DHCP IPs while `10.0.99.3 - 10.0.99.127` are IPs that I can statically assign. This is where the problem begins.

When the VM guest gets it's IP from the DHCP server, (10.0.99.128) the host adapter is connected to it and 10.0.99.1 can ping 10.0.99.128 and vice versa. However, **If I change the IP manually via nmtui**, (generating the following `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33` file) even though the vm can still access the internet, and ping other VMs, the host can't reach it and vice versa. What's going on? Is this because of the fact that I *didn't ask the DHCP server for a static IP*?! How do I fix this?

---

The config dump for the systems described above can be found at [this location](https://github.com/SomuSysAdmin-StackOverflow/ConfigDumps/tree/master/1.NetworkSetup_VMnet10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: The below method might or might not be necessary - however, this particular step is a *must*. A static route needs to be created on the guest interfaces, since the existing routing table may be wrong. Mine originally looked like:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.99.2       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
10.0.99.2       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens33
10.0.99.11      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens33
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

For this, a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens33` (route-*interface*) file should be created with the syntax:

```
default 10.0.99.2 dev ens33
10.0.99.0/24 dev ens33
```

Where `10.0.99.2` is the IP address of the Gateway (VMware NAT device) and `10.0.99.0/24` is the subnet in which the static IPs exist, i.e., the LAN Subnet. After this step, the interface has to be restarted using `nmcli c d ens33; nmcli c u ens33`. The kernel routing table should now look like:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.99.2       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
10.0.99.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
...
```

---

So, turns out we need to assign a static IP to the Guest VMs even when the guests are not working with DHCP. As such, the `dhcpd.conf` for the virtual switch needs to have entries for each static IP. Since I was using `vmnet10`, I edited the `/etc/vmware/vmnet10/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf` file and added:

```
...
####### VMNET DHCP Configuration. End of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #######

####### VMNET Static IP Allocation Table by Somu                 #######
host vmInfra.somuVMnet.local {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:79:8C:1F;
    fixed-address 10.0.99.99;
}

host vmPrime.somuVMnet.local {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:3B:B9:1C;
    fixed-address 10.0.99.11;
}

host vmDeux.somuVMnet.local {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:2A:E2:D3; 
    fixed-address 10.0.99.12;
}
```

Note that each MAC address corresponds to the virtual NICs as assigned for each VM. These configs should be added **after** the VMs have been shutdown, and vmware workstation itself has been turned off.

Finally, once the config has been saved, since the dhcp service runs on the host machine, they have to be restarted. Since I couldn't find the individual service for each VM, I simply restarted the `vmware.service` on the host itself. Note that I'm using `systemd` since I'm on Fedora 27. This method should work equally well for System V OSs as well, even though the command will be different.

```
systemctl restart vmware; systemctl status -l vmware
```

Ensure that the service is active, and then turn on your guest. Now, if you've configured your VM to have a static IP, then it must match the IP you set in `dhcpd.conf` just to avoid clashes. If using DHCP based automatic config, it's not a a problem at all, since the DHCP server will now assign the specific IP you requested based on the address of the MAC of the virtual NIC!

I hope this answer helps someone who is stuck in a similar situation and saves them the countless hours of searching. Note that I didn't have to turn off the firewall on either the host or the guest!

Comment: NAT is typically used when routing packets between two different network. And contrary to what you stated in your question, it is NOT a method for the host to communicate with the guest. In fact, it specifically blocks communication from outside hosts from reaching the guests unless you port forward. It almost appears your host and guests are on the same network address (10.0.99.x) therefore that is either not correct or you don’t have a NATted network setup. Perhaps you meant to use a “bridged” network? Otherwise you have to explain how 10.0.99.1 should ever be expected to ping 10.0.99.128.

Comment: @Appleoddity This is again, by the use of a virtual switch as it clearly states in the question - there is a virtual host adapter from the host to the LAN. The host sends traffic to the LAN if the ip matches, otherwise to the default gateway, thus bypassing the NAT when it needs to communicate with the hosts. The hosts however, gain the ability to connect to the internet behind a NAT and can have their own subnet, unlike when connecting to the bridge where the physical router 's DHCP assigns the ip, and so the guests can have a different subnet while still communicating with the host.

Comment: @Appleoddity It is also important to note that the host has the equivalent of dual NICs and thus can communicate with both networks by selecting the route for traffic.